# How to argue algebraically/rigorously that an event is not in the tail sigma-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

**Edit:** Let us define the tail sigma-algebra as $T = \cap_{i \in \mathbb{N}}T_i, T_i = \sigma((X_{n})_{n > i})$ of a sequence of random variables $X_n$.

All the examples I have seen so far about events belonging/not belonging to the tail sigma-algebra fall essentially to either i.) decomposing the event to a relationship with the $\lim\inf$ and $\lim\sup$ and using intersections, unions and complements to argue why an event belongs to the tail sigma-algebra or ii.) constructing such a sequence $X_1,X_2,\dots$ of r.v.s that some finite random variables $X_{i_1},\dots,X_{i_n}$ define the event in question, so that one can conclude *"Since this event depends on some finite collection of the elements of the random sequence, the event does not belong to the tail sigma-algebra"*.

But what if you'd want to argue about an event no belonging to the tail sigma-algebra in a more rigorous way?  E.g. let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be real valued r.v.s on the probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ and let $E = \{\omega \in \Omega\mid X_1 > 0\}$. Evidently this event does not belong to the tail sigma-algebra, but how would you argue about it with only the algebraic/set theoric definitions?

Comment: It *can* be the case that $E$ belongs to the tail $\sigma$-algebra. For example, if $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ are iid Poisson r.v.'s, and $$X_n=(-1)^{Y_1}Y_n,$$then $E\in T$. If you assume $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are independent, then it is obvious that $E\notin T$; did you mean to assume independence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, to show that an element is not in intersection, you need to show that it is not in some element.

For example, if $X_i$ are independent, then any event from $\sigma(X_i)$ if $i > 1$ is independent from any event from $\sigma(X_1)$. In particular, your $E \in \sigma(X_1)$ is independent from any event in $T_2$ and so is independent from $T$. As any event with non-zero and non-one probability is not independent from itself, it implies that if $P(E) \neq 0, 1$ then $E \notin T_2$ and so $E \notin T$.

If, for example, $E$ is empty ($X_1$ is always negative) then $E$, of course, is in $T$.

And if $X_i$ are not independent, then, in general, $E$ also can be in $T$. For example, if $X_1 = X_2 = \ldots$ then $T = T_i = \sigma(X_1)$, and so of course $E \in T$ in such case.